# vk.messages.getConversationMembers Почему не работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я написал код оснований на VkBotLongPoll при добавлении в беседу должен печатать информацию об ейо участниках но печатает информацию с сообщенный сообщества где чат этот не отображается, как решить?

```
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = VkApi(token="Токен")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "ID сообщества")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.from_chat == True:
        chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
        print(vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=200000000 + chat_id))
```

Comment: Текст вопроса неоч понятно написан. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы ожидали, что бот будет работать только в беседе, в которую он добавлен, но он также работает ещё и в сообщениях своего сообщества?
Суть примерно в том, что так и должно быть. Но там есть возможность определить именно в самом коде, в каком контексте сейчас находитесь, но не помню как.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский, Бот должен работать только в беседах и выводить информацию об участниках этой самой беседы в консоль типа: имя, фамилия, id и тд. Но проблема в другом а именно в самом методе который не работает,
прикол ище в том что если я добавляю бота в беседу с методом "messeges.send" то он прекрасно срабатывает но без этого числа "200000000" а просто "1" но для метода "getConversationMembers" необходимо число "200000000" с добавлением ID беседы. И да я без этого числа пробивал ничего не работает.